# debugging IE9 "only display secure content"

Tags: http, https, internet-explorer-9

I am getting  IE9 "only display secure content" warning on my page. It calls a large number of frames etc that I did not write so I am looking for way to get IE9 to show me what it considers the insecure (http) page that being asked to be loaded.  Is there a way to this? I also have access to IE7 & 8. I don't generally have any other tools on the machines with IE because they are just short term VMs, running MS's testing builds of IE7,8,9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), then click Allow in the warning.
Fiddler will show you all of the non-SSL requests.

You can also just look in Firebug's Net tab.

Comment: fiddler URL is fiddler2.com not what is post above. Still love the answer for supplying a non Windows specific way to solve this.